# How to convert existing image to A4 and set page orientation?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, pdf, paper-size

I'm aware the option to preset International Paper (such as A4) for New documents.

So I'm looking for similar/same option, but for the existing document without having to hardcode millimetres and dpi in Canvas Size? Or having creating new document and re-pasting and resizing it there?

Is there any simple option for setting page format (A4) and page orientation (e.g. landscape) for existing image in order to save it as PDF?

I'm using CS6, but any further version is fine as well.

Comment: I think the easiest way would be to resize the canvas in mm, can't imagine it getting simpler than that. Also, modifying the canvas lets you choose the direction in which the resizing will happen. If you need to do it for several documents, you can make it an action.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

2 options:

1. Go to `image>canvas` size and change the size to a4 (297x210). Use the arrows to select from where to enlarge
2. Crop adding an exact size:
   [image]

Answer (score 1):

Go to Image>Image Size and in the Fit To drop down selection box you can select A4 size. Simple and Photoshop does the calculations for you.

Answer (score 0):

This method is far from ideal and it works for PDF export (CS6 version):

1. Open print dialog (File->Print).
2. Set 'Scale to Fit Media'.
3. In Layout set your page orientation.
4. Go to: 'Print Settings...' for printer options.
5. Print to PDF.

   - On OSX by default it's: 'PDF -> Save as PDF...'
   - On Windows, additional software is required (e.g. CutePDF).

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Resize Buddy's retouching and editing tools. Also, you can use their [3000x3000 image converter](https://resizebuddy.com/3000x3000-image-converter/) to resize image dimensions for free.

Answer (score -3):

go to pictures > right click on picture > press print > click a4 > click full page photo [image]

Comment: However this isn't Photoshop?